# Access Property of a child class from Parent class

Tags: vb.net, oop

**Problem:**

I have made a class from JSON which I got supplied from an external company used to send orders to their system

**Part of the class:**

```
Public Class SalesOrder
  Public Class Field
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property FieldType() As String
        Get
            Return m_FieldType
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_FieldType = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FieldType As String
  End Class
End Class
```

**Case:**

Let's say I made a new instance of the SalesOrder class by taking a txt file with JSON and parsing the class from there, now I want to access the Name property inside of the Field class so I can edit it. How can I do this from a new instance of the SalesOrder class? Whenever I try to access it it will tell me it's a type and cannot be used as an expression

Example:

```
Dim sOrder As New SalesOrder
            sOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SalesOrder)(File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Something\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomethingElse\WebApplication1\OrderDefinitionJSON.txt"))
                    Dim FieldName As String = SOrder.Field.Name
```

This will cause an exception at sOrder.Field

**EDIT:**

**JSON**

This is part of the JSON I'm trying to read out:

```
{
    "BookDate": "2016-12-18T10:39:05.276Z",
    "BusinessObject": "SO1",
    "Table": {
        "Definition": {
            "Name": "SO_HDR",
            "Fields": [{
                "Name": "RowId",
                "FieldType": "C"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the instance of Field created in SalesOrder?

Comment: The SalesOrder class should have a property of type Field. Are you sure that you have a correct JSON ? Can you show a part of this file that you are trying to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class SalesOrder doesn't contain an istance of Field class. You have to add a property to SalesOrder class if you want to set it:

```
Public Class SalesOrder
  Public SalesField as Field
End Class

Public Class Field
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property FieldType() As String
        Get
            Return m_FieldType
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_FieldType = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FieldType As String
  End Class
```

Now, if you deserialized correctly and if SalesField is not nothing, you can:

```
Dim sOrder As New SalesOrder
            sOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SalesOrder)(File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Something\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomethingElse\WebApplication1\OrderDefinitionJSON.txt"))
                    Dim FieldName As String = SOrder.Field.Name
```